# Display object in designer, when selected in code

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

Looking at the code in winforms, is there a way to highlight, display, or otherwise go to the object in the designer?

For example, if the designer generated code has an event assigned to a button click:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DoSomething);
```

... is there any way to navigate back and see `button1` in the designer, short of looping through the properties for every object?

By the way, this is using VS 2013 for the IDE.

Comment: Well, you know it is "button1".  Select it from the combobox at the top of the Properties window.  Or click it in the View > Other Windows > Document Outline window.

Comment: yep that gets it. um, yeah, that combobox at the top of the properties window... yeah, i knew that was there, just needed someone to remind me :-P

Comment: @HansPassant think i should voluntarily delete this, or would you care to add as an answer? maybe this will help out someone down the road...

Comment: Just write your own answer if you think it is helpful and accept it, you don't need my help.